# How to suppress lint for all users of class/method

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, internationalization

I want this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("HardCodedStringLiteral")
public class Logger {
    public final String TAG;

    public Logger(String tag) { this.TAG = tag; }

    public void v(String msg) {Log.v(TAG, msg);}
    public void d(String msg) {Log.d(TAG, msg);}
    public void w(String msg) {Log.w(TAG, msg);}
    public void e(String msg) {Log.e(TAG, msg);}
    public void e(String msg, Throwable t) {Log.e(TAG, msg, t);}

}
```

Worked this way:
`Logger log = new Logger("AssetsUnpacker");`

But without any warnings. I don't want to suppress every log.v/log.e/(and so forth) call. I just want to uninternationalise all calls to my logger class (cause it's only for developer).

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress one or more issues if you declare as a Lint option in your build.gradle script (app target).

`lintOptions {
        disable 'HardCodedStringLiteral'
    }`

This will suppress all HardCodedStringLiteral warnings. Be careful suppressing this kind of warnings, your could have different problems or exceptions at runtime.

I hope this helps